# Change color statusBar Ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to change the color of statusBar in ANDROID. I used this code

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#E91E63');
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
```

I have no error in the console.

Comment: You are running on a device, correct? You can try to check if statusBar is visible: console.log('Is visible?',this.statusBar.isVisible);

Comment: I found the solution @HumbertodeCarvalho I needed to install the plugin  again $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently, the plugin Status Bar isn't available when you create a new project. Which is weird cause it's already used in  **app.component.ts**.

Anyway I just installed the plugin

```
 $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

then  **in app.component.ts**

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#87173c');
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
```